# Python - To check for strings that are partial similar

Tags: python-3.x

I want to ask that I am having data in the form:

```
"Data":[
   {
      "TradePairId":1261,
      "Label":"$$$/BTC",
      "AskPrice":0.00000038,
      "BidPrice":0.00000036,
      "Low":0.00000034,
      "High":0.00000038,
      "Volume":245611.54493283,
      "LastPrice":0.00000038,
      "BuyVolume":61190230.39331733,
      "SellVolume":10434778.71081393,
      "Change":8.57,
      "Open":0.00000035,
      "Close":0.00000038,
      "BaseVolume":0.08787847,
      "BuyBaseVolume":1.69560859,
      "SellBaseVolume":154560284.03335398
   },
   {
      "TradePairId":1263,
      "Label":"$$$/DOGE",
      "AskPrice":0.80000000,
      "BidPrice":0.50000072,
      "Low":0.50001005,
      "High":0.50001005,
      "Volume":0.0,
      "LastPrice":0.50001005,
      "BuyVolume":784338945.85694635,
      "SellVolume":199171.81421817,
      "Change":0.0,
      "Open":0.50001005,
      "Close":0.50001005,
      "BaseVolume":0.0,
      "BuyBaseVolume":23733.89175522,
      "SellBaseVolume":27405341.85800020
   },
   {
      "TradePairId":1262,
      "Label":"$$$/LTC",
      "AskPrice":0.00002895,
      "BidPrice":0.00001960,
      "Low":0.00002200,
      "High":0.00002200,
      "Volume":0.0,
      "LastPrice":0.00002200,
      "BuyVolume":539276.15940958,
      "SellVolume":567637.85244947,
      "Change":0.0,
      "Open":0.00002200,
      "Close":0.00002200,
      "BaseVolume":0.0,
      "BuyBaseVolume":0.37966392,
      "SellBaseVolume":1313.13194663
   },
   {
      "TradePairId":5181,
      "Label":"1337/BTC",
      "AskPrice":0.00000005,
      "BidPrice":0.00000004,
      "Low":0.00000004,
      "High":0.00000005,
      "Volume":18362406.71548798,
      "LastPrice":0.00000004,
      "BuyVolume":796558248.24106350,
      "SellVolume":705718844.66611060,
      "Change":0.0,
      "Open":0.00000004,
      "Close":0.00000004,
      "BaseVolume":0.79514855,
      "BuyBaseVolume":14.43608460,
      "SellBaseVolume":302726202.23174182
   },
   {
      "TradePairId":3944,
      "Label":"1337/DOGE",
      "AskPrice":0.05296980,
      "BidPrice":0.03760004,
      "Low":0.05000000,
      "High":0.05000000,
      "Volume":0.0,
      "LastPrice":0.05000000,
      "BuyVolume":1787712464.11137154,
      "SellVolume":11244356.11156200,
      "Change":0.0,
      "Open":0.05000000,
      "Close":0.05000000,
      "BaseVolume":0.0,
      "BuyBaseVolume":266027.93858629,
      "SellBaseVolume":872284118.43164375
   },
   {
      "TradePairId":3943,
      "Label":"1337/LTC",
      "AskPrice":0.00000260,
      "BidPrice":0.00000152,
      "Low":0.00000260,
      "High":0.00000260,
      "Volume":0.0,
      "LastPrice":0.00000260,
      "BuyVolume":74947197.56942268,
      "SellVolume":36196890.65558968,
      "Change":0.0,
      "Open":0.00000260,
      "Close":0.00000260,
      "BaseVolume":0.0,
      "BuyBaseVolume":26.50542485,
      "SellBaseVolume":2519903395.27105924
   },
   {
      "TradePairId":5313,
      "Label":"21M/BTC",
      "AskPrice":0.00004986,
      "BidPrice":0.00004420,
      "Low":0.00004433,
      "High":0.00005693,
      "Volume":10556.77600080,
      "LastPrice":0.00004500,
      "BuyVolume":1226185.96344030,
      "SellVolume":177194.04092096,
      "Change":-20.96,
      "Open":0.00005693,
      "Close":0.00004500,
      "BaseVolume":0.50858713,
      "BuyBaseVolume":0.85099172,
      "SellBaseVolume":25669.63041795
   },
   ....
]
```

I want to fetch the data of those index from this list, in which the first 3 charachters in keyword 'Label', is same, for the next three charachters after  '/' should only be "BTC", "USDT" or "NZDT"

for example: 1st index = "Label":"$$$/BTC" and 2nd index = "label":"$$$/USDT" so on the basis of first three letters in keyword "Label" i.e. "$$$" I want to fetch data of 1 index and 2 index, because the Letters are same in these index and second pair of letter is also "BTC" and "USDT" no matter if "$$$" is not present for "NZDT".

I know I'm not clear though, But Is this possible,
Thanks in advance

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code factory. Have you attempted to solve this yourself? Can you show your attempt and describe exactly what you're stuck on?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `re` module (regex) in python can do what you are asking for. Import it with `import re` and study its `compile()` function. You also might want to look at [this](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter7/).